# How to Parse the url data from ansible JSON output and extract the data

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-template, ansible-awx

I am working on a `AWX` ansible query, I got the output from the query and the data which I need is in a URL format which is a

```
'dn': "uni/infra/funcprof/accportgrp-xxxxxxxxxx/rtaccBaseGrp-[uni/infra/accportprof-xxxxxxxxxxxx/hports-xxxxxx-typ-range]"
```

I want to extract the `'xxxx'` data from the above string in ansible. I was able to do in python by splitting it with `/` and getting the details. Wondering how can I do that in Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

with the string in a variable named mystring:
you could do something like this:

```
{{ mystring.split("/")[1] | lower }}
```